# Creating a categorical variable for combinations of two variables in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have two variables, X and Y. I want to create a categorical variable for pairs of X and Y, that takes the same value for the same combinations of numbers in X and Y; for example the same value for (X=3, Y=7) and (X=7, Y=3):

```
obs   X   Y   cat_var
1     3   7      1
2     4   9      2
3     7   3      1
4     2   7      3
```

What would be the Stata code to do that?

Comment: Off-topic here as pure Stata but good enough for Stack Overflow. See advice in the Help Center on software-specific topics.

Comment: If it goes to Stack Overflow, they will want to see what you've tried. The Stata manual is quite detailed, is this anything close to what you want to do? https://www.stata.com/manuals13/drecode.pdf

Comment: @Michelle I am active on SO under the Stata tag (only Gold Badge at present).  This one is good enough. `recode` is not helpful here, as the solution depends on processing two variables first.

Answer (score 2):

```
gen xy1 = min(X, Y) 
gen xy2 = max(X, Y) 
egen catvar = group(xy1 xy2), label
```

See also [this paper for principles](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0043).

Comment: Thanks! It is a nice solution.

Comment: @D_B Since this helped, please select it as the answer.